An app changed file associations without my permission - how do I restore them?
I installed an AI coding IDE by dragging it to my Applications folder. As soon as I opened it, it changed my Finder such that all .md, .json, .txt etc. open with this new app instead of others. I do not remember giving permission to this app to make those changes. How do I revert the file associations/"open with" settings without uninstalling this new app?

You can reset the file associations, but this new app may seize them again.
To change the association for a particular file type, select any file of that type in the Finder and open the Info window. Select the app you want to open that type of file from the Open with: menu and then click the Change All... button.
To reset all file associations to the defaults, run this shell command, then log out:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain system -domain local -domain user


Is that command "safe" to run on 15.x Sequoia? I've read in a few places that 15 doesn't handle this LaunchServices db reset gracefully. Resulting in missing search results in System Settings and other oddities.
